# Eloquent SELECT "string" AS content_type causes errors

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using eloquent query builder in Laravel to help me create the equivalent of

```
SELECT name,'fund' AS content_type FROM fundraisers
```

This is what I tried:

```
$db = DB::table('fundraisers')->select("name,'fund' AS content_type")->get()->toArray();
```

But I get the error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;name,&#039;fund&#039;&#039; in &#039;field list&#039; (SQL: select `name,&#039;fund&#039;` as `content_type` from `fundraisers`)
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List the columns you want on `select` like this:

```php
$db = DB::table('fundraisers')
    ->select('name', DB::raw("'fund' as content_type"))
    //...
```

Check [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#selects) for more info.

Comment: Thanks I get a similar error: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;&#039;fund&#039;&#039; in &#039;field list&#039; (SQL: select `&#039;fund&#039;` as `content_te` from `nova_content`)`

Comment: @John You may use `DB::raw` check my updated answer please.

Comment: @John glad it helped :)